# Is it possible to resize image, re-encode video etc. in ArangoDB

Tags: arangodb

In CouchDB, I faced with a problem while getting many photos which I would use them on the client-side after resizing. Since downloading many megabytes and then resize them on the client-side isn't seem to be efficient, I need to find a way to download their resized versions.

Is that problem already resolved in ArangoDB? Can I resize images, re-encode videos and do some render on such stuff on the server side (in the database)?

Answer (score 0):

ArangoDB is a multi model Database, not a transcoder.

So while manipulating json objects is one of its core competencies, manipulating image and vidio data is definitely not.

For such a job you would choose [graphicsmagic](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/) for images, and [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) for videos.

There also [is the STI interface](http://technical.openmobilealliance.org/Technical/technical-information/release-program/current-releases/standard-transcoding-interface-v1-0) which can be used to remote transcoding. There even [is an open source implementation called Alembik](http://alembik.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I meant, if it is possible to use (trigger) some software on the server to make server side processing on objects - ie. without downloading, processing the data and pushing back to server.

Comment: You can operate i.e. Alembik via a shared directory; You can issue http requests via foxx queues. I'd advise not to try to fork processes or not to use synchroneus requests, as this will block your workers.